# i accidentally changed /var directory permissions on my server

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

i've been able to fix most of the files permissions, but lately i noticed i can't copy files from server to my local computer.

scp kept giving me this error

```
bash: /usr/bin/scp: Permission denied
```

i tried to see scp (binary file) permissions on the server and this is what i got

```
root@server1:/var# ls -altrh /usr/bin | grep scp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     71K Jul 26 16:20 lscpu
----------  1 root root     99K Nov  5 11:51 scp
```

not sure if that was my mistake or that's the default permissions that scp comes with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binaries in `/usr/bin` *typically* have file permissions `755` (some don't, such as `sudo` due to the setuid bit).

If `scp` is the only one affected, you could quickly fix this by running

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/scp
```